# nodejs Object.parse(native) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

in the node.js error

```
#SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/ssdbox/applications_modules/common/index.js:70:23)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:142:22)
Program node server.js exited with code 8

Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

Comment: Post your code for us to see.

Comment: This error usually means a forgotten closing operator -- using `{` without a matching `}`, for example. The lexer expected to find another, but reached the end of the code (file) first. Linters, such as [JSHint](http://jshint.com/), can help with resolving such issues.